# How to put circle above rectangle in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

> I want to make this layout (circle above rectangle)

[image]

[image]

> this is where i stuck

Comment: You should try on your own and post if you any issue

Comment: I tried but not achieving this layout

Comment: can you share your work...what you have done so far?

Comment: which type of layout are you using? This can be easily achieved through `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: constraint layout

Answer (score 0):

> I solved this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:context=".activity.fragments.profile_page">

<View
    android:id="@+id/view_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:background="@color/purple_500"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:letterSpacing="1"
    android:paddingVertical="10dp"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_circular_image_background"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/purple_200"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used constraint Layout for making this layout.

[see this layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBQZQ.png)

First, create a drawable resource file into your drawable.

go to, Drawable -> Right Click -> New -> Drawble Resource File -> Give Any name

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="oval"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:color="@color/white" android:width="2dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/black" />
</shape>
```

Second, Create your Layout in your Activity/Fragment

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".FragmentA">making
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Jonathan Wick"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circle"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvDashBoard"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDashBoard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:text="Dashboard"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/circle" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```